# How to correctly implement equals(), hashCode() if the values are within a range of each other?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

The criteria is that `equals()` method where the objects are considered equal if the value of the double variable is within +/- 10 of the other object's value of the double variable.

I'm not sure how to correctly implement `hashCode()` so that the hashCode would be equal if it satisfies the conditions of the `equals()` method.

I would really appreciate your input! Thanks!

```java
public class Test 
{
    private double value;

    private boolean isEqualValues (final double valueOne, final double valueTwo)
    {
        if(valueOne == valueTwo)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if((valueOne - valueTwo <= 10) &&
                (valueOne - valueTwo >= -10))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o)
    {
        if (this == o)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }

        Test test = (Test) o;

        if(isEqualValues(test.value, value))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //How to implement hashCode()
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        
        //unsure how to correctly implement hashCode() so that the hashCode would be equal if it 
        //satisfies the conditions of the equals() method above
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. This is a violation of the transitivity requirements of `equals()`.

Comment: You *could* do this if you were prepared to "bin" your objects, instead of comparing a range -- i.e. a == b if trunc(a/10) == trunc(b/10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to consistently implement this, since [`equals()` demands transitivity](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> It is *transitive*: for any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` should return `true`.

`new Test(1)`, `new Test(9)` and `new Test(14)` would fail that test (assuming a trivial one-argument constructor that assigns its argument to `value`).

One way to work around that is to not check for the absolute distance, but "categorize" your objects using some formula, for example take the floor of `value / 10` and compare that.

This way some "close" values like `new Test(9)` and `new Test(11)` would compare as not-equal, but other than that you'd get a similar result to what you described.

```
private long getEquivalenceGroup() {
    return Math.floorDiv((long) value, 10);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Test test = (Test) o;
    return test.getEquivalenceGroup() == this.getEquivalenceGroup();
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return Long.hashCode(getEquivalenceGroup());
}
```

As long as `getEquivalenceGroup()` is implemented in a stable manner this will produce "groups" of slightly different objects that still compare as equal and has a valid `hashCode()` implementation.

**Note:** **if** you want a comparison as described in the question **but** you don't necessarily need it to be returned by `equals()` then adding a `boolean isClose(Test other)` is perfectly fine. The *only* problem is you are trying to implement the `equals` method specifically with that semantic.

Comment: Could you provide an example as to how I can "categorize" objects? I couldn't quite grasp what you meant by categorizing objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't and you shouldn't.

You should implement a comparator and do such operations using that.

Comment: `Comparator.compare` should also be transitive.

Comment: @tgdavies Could you provide an example as to how I can use `Comparator.compare` to make it transitive? I'm unsure as to how I can achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: @casao01: It is mathematically impossible to have a transitive comparator that treats values as equal if they're close but not identical.

Comment: as mentioned by others it is impossible to achieve transitive comparison.

What you can do alternatively is to create ranges and if the numbers are in those range they will be equal. 

eg: [1,10] [11.20] and so on each number in such brackets will be considered equal.